# SUMIF with multiple ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried using a union with braces `{}` and `FLATTEN` to combine 2 simple ranges as the first input in a `SUMIF` formula. Neither worked. Summing 2 `SUMIF` formula works of course but that's not really a solution but a short-term workaround.

1. Try, doesn't work:

   ```
   =SUMIF({B3:B5;E3:E5},"yes",{A3:A5;D3:D5})
   ```
2. Try, doesn't work:

   ```
   =SUMIF(FLATTEN(B3:B5,E3:E5),"yes",FLATTEN(A3:A5,D3:D5))
   ```
3. Try, works crappily:

   ```
   =SUMIF(B3:B5,"yes",A3:A5)+SUMIF(E3:E5,"yes",D3:D5)
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend this approach:

```
=SUM(FILTER({A:B;D:E},{B:B;E:E}="yes"))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of the `SUMIF` function.

When working with arrays you can use `SUM(FILTER())` instead:

```
=sum(filter({A3:A5;D3:D5},{B3:B5;E3:E5}="Yes"))
```